# If two different objects have same key name, merge their value

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6

```
let obj1 = { names: ["Zack","Cody"]};
let obj2 = { names: ["John","Jake"] };
```

Results in: `obj1 = { names: ["Zack","Cody","John","Jake"]}`

What I have tried:

```
if (Object.keys(obj1) == Object.keys(obj2)) {
  Object.values(obj1) = [...Object.values(obj1), ...Object.values(obj2)];
}
```

Comment: Why don't the names get merged too?

Comment: `obj1.names.push(...obj2.names)`? You can't assign to a function call like `Object.values()`.

Comment: What about for other keys not named `names`?

Comment: @kmoser I refactored the question

Comment: @ggorlen I just tried putting that line inside the if statement but obj1 still comes back with Zack and Cody only

Answer (score 2):

Iterate through the keys in `obj1`, and for every one that exists in `obj2`, merge its values into `obj1`:

```
let obj1 = { names: ["Zack","Cody"]};
let obj2 = { names: ["John","Jake"] };

Object.keys(obj1).forEach(function(k) {
    if ( obj2[k] ) { // obj2 contains this key
        obj1[k].push( ...obj2[k] ) // Add the values from obj2's key to obj1's key
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just iterate over each objects properties and add them to the new object if that property does not exist. To deal with merges where the same key exists in other objects we can define a merge strategy function that will resolve the conflict.

```
let obj1 = { names: ["Zack","Cody"]};
let obj2 = { names: ["John","Jake"] };

function mergeObjs(objects, mergeStrategy) {
    mergeStrategy = mergeStrategy || ((oldV, newV) => newV);
    const result = {};
    for (let ob of objects) {
        for (let [k, v] of Object.entries(ob)) {
            const oldV = result[k];
            result[k] = (oldV == undefined) ? v: mergeStrategy(oldV, v); 
        }
    }
    return result;
}

console.log(mergeObjs([obj1, obj2], (oldV, newV) => oldV.concat(newV)));
```

the function only allows one strategy per merge, which might be a bit limiting for more complex cases but for simple ones like this its ok.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you were comparing two arrays - `Object.keys(obj1)` and `Object.keys(obj2)`. This condition would never be true because no two arrays are equal because they have reference to different memory location.

To deal with this, you can compare their contents. This is what I am doing in the below snippet -

```js
let obj1 = { names: ["Zack","Cody"]};
let obj2 = { names: ["John","Jake"]};

if (Object.keys(obj1)[0] ==  Object.keys(obj2)[0]) { 
  Object.values(obj1)[0].push(...Object.values(obj2)[0]);
  console.log(obj1.names); 
}
```

I am only comparing the first keys in both objects in the above snippet. If you like to do this for every key in both objects, then you can use a loop with indexes replacing the `[0]`.

**Note** - If you are going to use the above approach, then the order of keys in both objects matters.

Comment: This isnt what I am looking for, if they have the same key name thats when I want to do that to the value of obj1 because my object has different keys names

Comment: @teestunna can you check my updated answer and tell me if this solves you issue?

Answer (score 1):

You could concat the value by wrapping into array element and flatten (or `concat`  as @ggorlen suggested in the comment) it

```js
let obj1 = { names: ["Zack", "Cody"] }
let obj2 = { names: ["John", "Jake"] }

const mergeObj = (obj1Raw = {}, obj2Raw = {}) => {
  // shallow clone for demo only
  let obj1 = { ...obj1Raw }
  let obj2 = { ...obj2Raw }

  for (const prop in obj2) {
    if (obj1.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
      obj1[prop] = [obj1[prop], obj2[prop]].flat()
    } else {
      obj1[prop] = obj2[prop]
    }
  }

  return obj1
}

console.log(mergeObj(obj1, obj2))
```

Comment: If `.flat()` isn't supported you can use `[...obj1[prop], ...obj2[prop]]` or `obj1[prop].concat(obj2[prop])`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one-liner using `Object.entries`, `Object.fromEntries` and `Array#map`, assuming the properties share the same key name are always arrays:

```js
let obj1 = { names: ["Zack","Cody"] };
let obj2 = { names: ["John","Jake"] };

const result = { 
  ...obj1, 
  ...Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj2).map(([k, v]) => [
    k, obj1[k] ? [...obj1[k], ...v] : v
  ]))
};

console.log(result);
```

Comment: @Mhmdrz_A Lol, typical abuse case of ES6

Answer (score 1):

You can try [lodash.merge](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#merge), powerful function to merge multiple objects

```
var object = {
  'a': [{ 'b': 2 }, { 'd': 4 }]
};
 
var other = {
  'a': [{ 'c': 3 }, { 'e': 5 }]
};
 
_.merge(object, other);
// => { 'a': [{ 'b': 2, 'c': 3 }, { 'd': 4, 'e': 5 }] }
```